# Nuxt 3 on Github pages with nuxt-svgo: "Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided"

Tags: github-pages, nuxtjs3

I'm building my Nuxt 3 application to Github Pages by running "npm generate" to build the static files. While the dev and production builds work fine locally, it doesn't work when it gets pushed to Github Pages.

When I open the Github Pages site, I get the error:

```
Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('https://customdomain.com/_nuxt/logo.6cc77fc4.svg') is not a valid name.
```

What perplexes me is when I navigate to `https://customdomain.com/_nuxt/logo.6cc77fc4.svg`, the SVG image exists! Why isn't it able to load it then?

Comment: Try to host it on Netlify/Vercel for debugging purposes. Where are your images located in the project? Not sure that this one should have the hash part.

Comment: This is only a problem for svgs, and I have them located in /assets/svg. I have a suspicion that the problem might have to do with the nuxt-svgo module attempting to make the SVG into a component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was all a side effect of having the "actions/configure-pages@v3" action run as a step in my Github Actions deployment workflow. I copied the file from GitHub's own template, but using it caused parts of my site to not build -- including the svgs, TailwindCSS, etc.

Here's my final workflow file:

```yaml
# Sample workflow for building and deploying a Nuxt site to GitHub Pages
#
# To get started with Nuxt see: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/get-started/installation
#
name: Deploy Nuxt site to Pages

on:
  # Runs on pushes targeting the default branch
  push:
    branches: ['main']

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# Sets permissions of the GITHUB_TOKEN to allow deployment to GitHub Pages
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

# Allow only one concurrent deployment, skipping runs queued between the run in-progress and latest queued.
# However, do NOT cancel in-progress runs as we want to allow these production deployments to complete.
concurrency:
  group: 'pages'
  cancel-in-progress: false

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '16'
          cache: npm
          cache-dependency-path: './package-lock.json'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Static HTML export with Nuxt
        run: npm run generate
      - name: Deploy
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4
        with:
          branch: gh-pages # The branch the action should deploy to.
          folder: .output/public # The folder the action should deploy.
          token: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
```